# Failed to configure data source from application.yml in SpringBoot Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, spring-data-jpa, yaml

I am using `application.yml` file to configure data source. When I run the jar file, I get the exception.

It works fine if I run project in IntelliJ (run button)

Command I use to build and run jar

```
./gradlew build -x check   

java -jar build/libs/UrlShortener-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5332/dbName
    username: username
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Exception

```
05:13:50.339 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.7.22"
}

group = "url.shortener"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "url.shortener.UrlShortenerApplicationKt"
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })

}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    val kotlinxHtmlVersion = "0.8.0"
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:$kotlinxHtmlVersion")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But if I configure through kotlin, it works

```
@Configuration
class Config {

    @Bean
    fun getDataSource(): DataSource {
        val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5332/dbName")
        dataSourceBuilder.username("username")
        dataSourceBuilder.password("password")
        return dataSourceBuilder.build()

    }
}
```

Comment: 2 Things: maybe a typo in connection jdb/driver name, or maybe missing driver library

Comment: @Antoniossss yml works if I run through IntelliJ.

Comment: then issue could be 1. yml is not in the jar or 2. you have some profile in the cli/env that stops the file being picked.

Comment: @PrasadU this is the repo https://github.com/iamanbansal/kt-spring-boot-url-shortener

Comment: and when it does not work for you?

Comment: Ah ok so you dont know how to package the application. Voting to close as irrelevant code is provided, no details or curcomstances are provided (eg the fact it does not work after packaging but works in ide)

Comment: @Antoniossss Sorry my bad, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking out your customisation for jar seems to resolve the issue.

```
//tasks.withType<Jar> {
//  manifest {
//      attributes["Main-Class"] = "url.shortener.UrlShortenerApplicationKt"
//  }
//  duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
//  from({
//      configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
//  })
//
//}
```

Comment: it throws an exception that the main class not found, that's why I added this.

Comment: may be because you are trying to use the `-plain.jar` ; use the normal jar - spring boot packaging works fine.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I was aware diff between -plain.jar and .jar